# Cannot understand the problem of Bitonic Euclidean Traveling-Salesman

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, euclidean-distance

I am referring to the problem in Introduction to Algorithms. I kind of fail to understand the problem.

From what I see,  I need to sort the x-coordinates of the given set of points and then form a optimal path from the smallest x coordinate to the largest x coordinate.

For eg. (x1,y1) (x2,y2) ...(xn,yn) are sorted points. The optimal path is x1-x2-x3...xn.

What am I missing here? How does dynamic programming come into picture here?

Comment: try at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Before posting on cstheory, please take a look through the existing questions there regarding such problems. Here on SO, unfortunately, it is off-topic.

Comment: @Lasse, if it's suitable for cstheory.stackexchange.com why is it closed and not just migrated ?

Comment: Because as I said, there's already many such questions there. If the future of the question is likely to be that it is closed as a duplicate on the target site, there is usually not a point in migrating it.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen - From cstheory's FAQ: "We welcome research-level questions in theoretical computer science...". Finding an optimal euclidean TSP bitonic tour is often assigned in an undergrad algorithms course - hardly research-level material. Since algorithms are definitely on-topic on SO (second FAQ bullet), I move to re-open.